# MobaXterm Mosh client unable to connect to remote hosts with usage error

Tags: windows, ssh

When using MobaXterm's Mosh client on Windows 10/64 to connect to remote hosts I get the following usage error

```
/bin/moshsession usage:
  /bin/moshsession <server_name> <user_name> [<ssh_port_number> <locale> <Prediction_type> <mosh_server_command> <Mosh_ports_range> <Ssh_private_key>]
```

[image]

When attempting to connect to/from any UNIX host (Slackware, Debian 10, OpenBSD) from Bash or any other shell using my standard OpenSSh client with the following command line, I have no problem and everything works well:

```
mosh --ssh=\"ssh -p 50515\" -p 60050 username@hostname.sld.tld
```

Even trying to connect to a remote host from a UNIX VM within VirtualBox on my Windows workstation works as it should using the method above in Bash.

I've configured the advanced settings in the MobaXterm Mosh session manager to reflect the UDP port I want to connect to on the mosh-server as well as the (TCP) SSH port - in this case, 50515. It matters not whether a specify a UDP port to connect to the mosh-server or just leave it blank and accept the default.

[image: Mosh Advanced Settings dialog]

The only thing that  appears to make a difference is if I fill in the username field. If I leave it blank, I get the error above (as it appears in the screenie), if I fill in the username field, then nothing, it acts like it's waiting for a response from the server while it connects (like what you would receive during SSH session connection negotiations). It doesn't time out or anything.

My firewall ports for UDP 60000-61000 are open, etc., But I can't figure out why I can't connect via MobaXterm. Using MobaXterm to connect using SSH itself is no problem.

What am I doing wrong? Or what might I try to correct this issue?

Comment: I too faced this issue but could not find a solution. An alternative is to use the official mosh client from https://mosh.org/
If your problem was resolved, please let me know.

Comment: Yeah, MobaXTerm is just so convenient though when using Windows, much like Remmina under UNIX. I just pretty much stick to running Slackware-current or Arch Linux as my fault drivers nowadays and forgo using Windows if at all possible. It would still be nice to have a handy and aesthetically pleasing solution for Windows though.... Like Remmina, although in Linux i tyoically just use gnome-terminator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this qualifies more as a comment instead of an answer, but this workaround is nearly good as the one that we are trying to achieve.

> 1. Install Docker on Windows and run a centos/ubuntu container.
> 2. Install mosh on that container (Install this via a Dockerfile, or commit the container with mosh into a new image and launch this one henceforth).
> 3. Install mosh on the remote server and login from the above container.

PS: Posting this as an answer for more visibility.

Comment: Well, you're right. It's not actually an answer that I was looking for. I was hoping for a native Windows solution, preferably with respect to MobaXTerm. But I'm marking your answer as the correct answer here anyway because I've never found a solution and even though it's not much different than me spinning up a VM, it is a lighter method and available without having to launch VirtualBox and eat up all that memory (even though I almost always have a UNIX VM running anyway). Thanks for your suggestion, it's certainly as good as any other I've come up with :)